# Are these pictures of the recent terrorist attack in Kenya (NSFW)?

Tags: terrorism, africa

There is a post going around facebook about [the recent terrorist attack in Kenya](http://www.theguardian.com/world/2015/apr/03/al-shabaab-atrocity-kenyan-officials-under-fire-for-failure-to-protect-students) with the following pictures *(spoiler'ed for queezy stomachs)*:

Warning, graphic images (18+):

> [image: picture 1]
>  [image]

And the following description:

> A vicious murderous massacre of university students took place in Kenya in Africa a few days ago by Islamic terrorist group Al-Shabab with over 147 dead.
>
> But unlike the Je Suis Hebdo massacre in France when the WORLD STOPPED the WORLD is happily enjoying their Easter festivities with NO MARCH BY WORLD LEADERS in Narobi or Garissa.
>
> And our own African Union, African leaders and Religious Leaders especially within the Moslem community are as silent as DEATH.

Are these really pictures from that attack?  The second one in particular looks very unnatural - everyone is face-down, packed together tight, almost no blood, no apparent physical injuries, etc.

I tried googling the images, but most of the results seem to be non-credible news sources *(though most are in foreign languages, so it's hard for me to tell)*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this BBC article today, [Kenya student killings: BBC gains access to Garissa dormitories](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-africa-32236022), the poster image for the video appears to be a picture of the same room/location as the second photograph shown above.

[image]

That implies that at least the second photograph in the OP are "really pictures from that attack".

The source of the images appears to be a [Facebook post](https://www.facebook.com/yawbuobu.ernest/posts/10152962424128462) by [Nana Yaw Buobu](https://www.facebook.com/yawbuobu.ernest) (who [appears to be Ghanaian](http://www.ghanaweb.com/GhanaHomePage/NewsArchive/artikel.php?ID=291751)). The photos have been credited to him by two large media outlets. One is Brazil's [Globo](http://g1.globo.com/mundo/noticia/2015/04/campanha-no-twitter-mostra-quem-sao-vitimas-de-ataque-no-quenia.html) (a part of [Grupo Globo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grupo_Globo)) and the other is India's [Indiatimes](http://www.indiatimes.com/news/world/where-is-our-jesuischarlie-ask-african-terror-victims-sympathizers-231617.html) (a part of [Times Internet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Times_Internet)). An excerpt from the machine-translation of the Globo piece reads:

> Also generated reviews two photos posted on Facebook that show stacked bodies in what would be the will of the university after the attack. Nana Yaw Buobu, who posted the image, said in a recent post on your profile that was criticized for disseminating the image, but that reproduction has made ​​people around the world returned his eyes to the atrocity.

Comment: Caveat: I haven't watched the video I referenced.

Comment: I watched it, it seems SFW.

Comment: I can see it implies that the photos were taken at the same location, but the OP's implication seemed to be that it might be posed with living people. Does this address that?

Comment: @Oddthinking This doesn't address that: this only claims that it's the right location. IMO the timing (that the photos in question were published soon after the massacre) implies that it wasn't posed with living people, but that's not part of this answer.

Comment: This is enough to make me believe the photos are real; but what happened to cause the victims to end up in such unnatural poses?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft [According to this article](http://www.nytimes.com/2015/04/04/world/africa/kenyan-students-describe-shabab-attack-on-garissa-university-college.html?_r=0), `Survivors said many students had fallen for the militants’ trick, voluntarily leaving their dorm rooms and obeying commands to lie down in neat rows, only to be shot in the back of the head.`, and, `“They were shooting people as they came out; they were making others lie down,” said a doctor who was not authorized to speak publicly. “They had so many people lying in one place, it was easy killing.”`